# r and p-value uf chi-square-test

Tags: r, chi-squared

I am creating random multinomial samples (with equal probabilities) and for each sample computing the chi-square-value and the corresponding chi-value.

Replicating the experiment and plotting the p-value (which in my understanding shlut be uniformly distributed) I get reasonable density plot but a very strange histogram.

Here is the code

```
roulette <- function(n){
  rmultinom(1,n,rep(1/37,37)) |>
    as.vector() |>
    set_names(0:36)
}


roulette_p_wert <- function(n){
  chisq.test(roulette(n))$p.value
}

replicate(100000,roulette_p_wert(200)) ->
  p_vals

hist(p_vals,breaks=100)
plot(density(p_vals))
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question here? Is this a specific programming question? Or if you are uncertain of the statistics going on, you should probably ask for help at [stats.se] instead.

Answer (score 1):

With as few as 200 samples, there are only a limited number of values that the pvalue can take. The gaps between them are more spread out in the middle than at the edges, hence the effect of missing bars and a hump in the bar chart. Increasing the number of breaks to 1000 makes it clearer what's happening with the values being more likely but more spread out in the middle than at the edges.

[image: Output plot]

Comment: Thanks, thats the explanation.